# JavaScript in StringBuilder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-3.5

I can't seem to add some javascript to a StringBuilder.  I have a working page which generates HTML content in the form of a div tag.  This works fine.  I just wanted to add a simple script at the end of the StringBuilder so the client side gets an alert when the div tag finishes appearing on the screen, i.e:

```
objStringBuilder.Append("<script language='javascript'>")
objStringBuilder.Append("alert('Finished');")
objStringBuilder.Append("</script>")
```

This gives me an error message in the IDE:

```
statement cannot appear within a method body.  end of method assumed
```

The error is appearing on the last line:

```
objStringBuilder.Append("</script>")
```

This code is done in VB.NET, hence no semi-colons like C#.

Comment: Er, where are your semi-colons? :)

Comment: No semi-colons in VB.NET, it's in the tag, and I have just updated the question to make this clear.

Comment: When you say "Error in the IDE", do you mean a compile error? If so, http://www.aspnet101.com/2008/06/statement-cannot-appear-within-a-method-body-end-of-method-assumed/

Comment: I copy pasted the code you provide, and I cannot reproduce. It might come from somewhere else.

Comment: Not a compile time error, a syntax error, i.e. when I finish typing the string builder, it gets a blue squiggly line underneath it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a (big) guess here.

- assumption: you are working within `script runat="server"` blocks
- assumption: closing the script tag (even as a string) closes the server block
- server block is now malformed

Alternatively, it could be a malformed Sub or Function block.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by changing `objStringBuilder.Append("</script>")` to `objStringBuilder.Append("</scr" & "ipt>")`...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested from Asp.net forum:

> to Insert Javascript from codebehind I prefer you to use
>
> RegisterClientScript instead of plane string deployment to aspx page
>
> you can use code like

```
 ScriptManage.RegisterClientScript(this.GetType(), "", "your javascript
    code", true);
```

> or

```
> Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScript("", "your javascript code",
> true);
```

> you need to use your javascript code without  tag name

http://forums.asp.net/t/1683634.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
Sb.Append("alert('Finished');");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", Sb.ToString(), true);
```